# CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property '_Default.txtEditValue'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

When I click a button it gets the value of that button(Id) and pass it to the code behind page

----Ajax Code------

```
.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CS.aspx/Edit", 
            data: "{'dt1':'" + dt1 +"'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json", 
            success: function(result)
             {
                alert(result.d);
             }
        });
```

Edit is the method that i used in code behind page

----code behind page code------

```
public static string Edit(string dt1)
{
    string pcId = dt1;
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=192.168.0.133;User Id=123; " + "Password=123;Database=checDB;"); 
    try
     {
            conn.Open(); 
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select Center_Id,center_Name from tbl_Profit_Centers where Center_Id = " + pcId, conn);
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            txtEditValue.Text = dr["center_Name"].ToString();
            conn.Close();
return "Select Success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "failure";
        }
}
```

this error shows me when run the project

> CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property '_Default.txtEditValue'

give me a step by step answer new to this

Comment: Why is the `Edit` method marked as `static`? Remove that and it should work.

Comment: already tried Not working is there any other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access form elements inside `static` methods because your `form` is a `class` and elements on this form are like `children` of this form so you cannot directly access `form elements` inside static methods. What you can do is `return value` from `WebMethod` which you want to set in textbox and set value in `success of ajax`.

> You are reading value from datareader after you have closed the connection. Datareader needs an open connection to read data you should close the connection after you have read the data from datareader. Also you have to call `Read()` method of datareader in order to get data.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Edit(string dt1)
{
string pcId = dt1;
string strToReturn="";
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=192.168.0.133;User Id=123; " + "Password=123;Database=checDB;"); 
try
 {
   conn.Open(); 
   NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select Center_Id,center_Name from tbl_Profit_Centers where Center_Id = " + pcId, conn);
   NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
   while(dr.Read())
   {
    strToReturn= dr["center_Name"].ToString();
   }
   conn.Close();
  }
catch (Exception ex)
  {
    strToReturn= "failure";
  }
    return strToReturn;
```

}

```
.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CS.aspx/Edit", 
        data: "{'dt1':'" + dt1 +"'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json", 
        success: function(result)
         {
            $('input[id$=txtEditValue]').val(result.d);
         }
    });
```

Comment: What failure message ?

Comment: So what is the failure message ?

Comment: it display failure in the textbox but  i need the value from the table

Comment: Because you are getting exception please debug and check what is exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79316/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-swathi-venugopal).